# How to ignore folder/files from npm link in a monorepo?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working in a monorepo, where packages have dependency on each other. However some directories such as nyc/ are getting copied to other packages' node_modules folder. How do I prevent this? can .npmignore help here.

```
root
|------A
       |----nyc/
       |----dist
|------B
       |-----node_modules
       |          |-------A
       |                   |----nyc //how to ignore this?
       |                   |----dist
       |
       |-----dist
```

Comment: Dis you find the solution ?

Comment: @ThéoChampion no sorry, I did a workaround. My problem was my pipeline was copying these nyc files multiple times, so I ignored them there. Maybe you can explore npmignore for the solution.